# Fan speed semi-permanently at max despite PRM & SMC reset & setting fan speed manually

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I have a 13-inch MacBook Pro from early 2011, with custom SSD & Memory upgrade.

For the last few months, the fan has been running at max speed or close to it.

To fix it, I've tried:

- Resetting the PRAM
- Resetting the SMC
- Replacing the fan
- Starting in Safe Boot mode
- Setting the fan speed manually with an app called tg Pro

These are the temperature readings outputted by tg Pro on my machine.

[image: Temperature readings]

The only way I can silent the fans is to override the Mac's native fan control system and turn it down, but then I'd probably be damaging the internal components.

Some things that could help diagnose the problem:
 - When I started in Safe Boot mode, there were some visual artifacts in the form of horizontal bars going across the screen. I did a screen capture with Quicktime but strangely enough the visual artifacts were not present. These artifacts do not appear when I boot in normal mode.

I suspect it is a hardware problem and I'm three quarters tempted to schedule a rendezvous with the Apple Store but if you have anything else I could try I'm all ears.

Comment: When did you install the SSD? I have some Compaq servers that max the fans because the hard drives are not reporting the drive temp properly via SMART. Not saying that's the issue but I am wondering if there is a correlation there.

Comment: At 8 years old, I'd be thinking cracked thermal paste; needs a strip & replace. Fans ought to be running at 78°, but they should be capable of dropping that temperature. If they can't, then something else is preventing cooling... hence my thought. [btw, starting in safe mode disables GPU acceleration, hence the artefacts]

Comment: What does activity monitor show on cpu used?

Comment: @ThomasNelson The SSD was installed years ago, but the fan problem appeared much later.

Comment: @Tetsujin hmm thanks for the tip, I'll check that out

Comment: @Mark I don't know if it's normal or not, but sometimes programs seem to take a lot of CPU. This is an example: https://imgur.com/a/v82arwo

Comment: In that example, Spark is using all of one core, which is not unusual for an intense process, but a bit odd for an email client. [Activity Monitor works 'per core' in the top table & 'all cores added' only at the bottom, showing 40% 'free time']

Comment: One process using 90% cpu would be enough to keeythe fans on. I think you need to monitor what is running especially in safe mode.